# Why is my timestamp's milliseconds the same as it's seconds?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, timestamp

I am using the following formula:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'HH:mm:ss:SSS" - "dd/MM');
}


function onEdit(e) {
  const excludeSheetNames = ["START", "MASTER"]; // Please set exclude sheet names.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  //if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || ![2, 4].includes(range.columnStart) || range.rowStart == 1) return;

  range.offset(0, 1).setNumberFormat('HH:mm:ss:SSS" - "dd/MM').setValue(new Date());

  if (e.value != "TRUE") return;
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('HH:MM:SS - dd/MM ');
}
```

The result is always like the attached picture:
[image: Timestamp]

The milliseconds return the same number like the seconds. Why?

```
15:34:33:033 - 25/10
15:34:35:035 - 25/10
15:34:36:036 - 25/10
15:34:37:037 - 25/10
15:34:39:039 - 25/10

16:21:24:024 - 25/10
16:21:25:025 - 25/10
16:21:28:028 - 25/10
16:21:29:029 - 25/10
16:21:30:030 - 25/10
```

Comment: The milliseconds cannot be the same with seconds. Usually differs. Let's say you are fast and you make 2 options in the same second. The milliseconds can not always be the same as seconds always there is a deviation for example 17:19:25:025 - 25/10
17:19:25:232 - 25/10. It is counting not translating the seconds to milliseconds. Like a stopwatch. I do not know if my example is clear.

Comment: See the title. It summarizes the question and actually asks a question. This is how titles should be...

Comment: Yes Yes Yes!!! It is working! I replaced in row 2 & 14!

Comment: Ref: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_time_format_patterns

Comment: "See the title. It summarizes the question and actually asks a question. This is how titles should be.." With your help, I will learn eventually! You should enable emojis in the comments it would be easier to express my feelings toward you!!!

Comment: 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255735/discussion-between-dek-and-themaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number format for milliseconds is incorrect.

As written in [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_time_format_patterns),

> `0` - Tenths of seconds. You can increase the precision to two digits with 00 or three digits (milliseconds) with 000.

> `ss` - Seconds in the minute with a leading 0.

Replace

```
HH:mm:ss:SSS - dd/MM
```

with

```
HH:mm:ss.000 - dd/MM
```